# Rest of AppleScript is ignored when I use a variable in posix path

Tags: variables, applescript, posix

I'm using AppleScript in Automator to copy a page's source and save it to a file. For some reason when I use a variable (titleVal) in the posix path, the rest of my code in my loop is ignored, including the file that never gets written.

I updated the code before with my full AppleScript in case it has to do with more than the few lines I had before. I'm using Automator with specified Finder items in this order: "urlList.txt" and fileList.txt".

```
    on run {input, parameters}
        set updateCount to 0
        read (item 1 of input)
        set ps to paragraphs of the result
        set tot to count ps
        set TLFile to (("Users:Admin:Desktop:download captions:") as text) & "fileList.txt"
        set TLLines to paragraphs of (read file TLFile as «class utf8»)
        tell application "Safari"
            reopen
            activate
        end tell
        repeat with i from 1 to tot
            set p to item i of ps
            if p is not "" then
                try
                    tell application "Safari"
                        tell front window

                            set r to make new tab with properties {URL:"https://www.youtube.com/timedtext_editor?v=" & p & "&lang=en&name=&kind=&contributor_id=0&bl=vmp&action_view_track=1"}


                            set current tab to r

                            set titleVal to item i of TLLines
                            set updateCount to updateCount + 1
                            do shell script "echo The value: " & updateCount



                            delay 2

                            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('movie_player').outerHTML = ''" in current tab

                            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('creator-page-sidebar').outerHTML = ''" in current tab

                            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('footer').outerHTML = ''" in current tab

                            delay 3

                            do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default action-track-button flip yt-uix-menu-trigger')[0].click()" in current tab

                            delay 1



                            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('aria-menu-id-2').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[5].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()" in current tab

                            delay 4

-- using a variable in path1 is where it screws up. try changing it to another variable value and it will have the same effect.
                            set myString to source of current tab
                            set path1 to "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/" & titleVal & ".srt"
                            say path1
                            set newFile to POSIX file path1

                            --set newFile to POSIX file "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/test.xml.srt"

                            open for access newFile with write permission
                            write myString to newFile
                            close access newFile

                            -- i have exit repeat here to only test the first loop
                            exit repeat 

                        end tell
                    end tell
                end try
            end if
        end repeat
    end run
```

Without a variable works fine, but I need the variable to make the script work properly in a loop. I've checked the value of the var. I also tried "& quoted form of titleVal &".

Update: When I remove the try/end try as suggested to get the error, the error is:
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Safari got an error: Can’t get POSIX file "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/test.srt" of window 1.”

Comment: The variable titleVal needs to be set before it can be used...  set titleVal to ....

Comment: titleVal is set and was checked.

Comment: titleVal variable is not included In the code that you posted in your question.  It's kind of difficult for us to troubleshoot the problem with fragmented code

Comment: Okay I updated the question including titleVal

Comment: This code is supposed to work. By the way, you don't need the `POSIX file` line, `open for access` accepts also POSIX paths. But you should add a proper error handling to close the file reliably on failure.

Comment: Try `display dialog path1` maybe. Or try a path without a space in it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Space characters are crucial only in `do shell script` calls.

Comment: @vadian Ok, thank you - just trying to help get OP up and running ;-)

Comment: I used "say" for the path, and it sounds correct. Still, if I use a variable in the path, it skips everything after it. I'm going to update the post with the full code with the loop and everything. Try it out with yourself if you want with automator.

Comment: Updated code in post.

Comment: Remove or comment out the `try` and `end try` lines to get an error message.

Comment: Maybe try starting Terminal and running `ls -l "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/test.xml.srt"` There is a space between `download` and `captions`.

Comment: I removed try and end try to get an error. Thank you. "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/test.xml.srt" works (with space between download and captions) in the AppleScript. It's just when I use a variable, it gives me the error: The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Safari got an error: Can’t get POSIX file "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/test.srt" of window 1.”

Comment: user3439894 are you sure that is true? Because without the variable there is still a space in the path, and it works fine. I tried setting newFile by using "set newFile to POSIX file quoted form of path1" which gives me the error "Can’t get quoted form of window 1". I've also tried to escape the space between download and captions (which seems like a non-issue) but it gives me the error "Expected “"” but found unknown token."

Comment: @user3439894 That's wrong. Spaces in POSIX paths are **only** relevant in `do shell script` calls

Comment: Sorry, didn't thoroughly read the OP, code and comments.

Comment: At this point, this seems to be more of a bug in Automator/AppleScript than a coding issue. Are there any alternatives to do the same thing that I'm trying to achieve in Automator+AppleScript?

Comment: It's not an `Automator/AppleScript` bug, it's a *scripter* bug  Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I fixed it by changing one line. See my answer too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you are going to write the file in the `tell window` block of Safari which cannot work.

I recommend to use a separate handler. Put the `on writeFile` handler outside of the `on run` handler. I added reliable error handling and the data are saved UTF-8 encoded.

```
on writeFile(theData, fileName)
    set newFile to "/Users/Admin/Desktop/download captions/downloadedCaptions/" & fileName & ".srt"
    try
        set fileDescriptor to open for access newFile with write permission
        write theData to fileDescriptor as «class utf8»
        close access fileDescriptor
    on error
        try
            close access newFile
        end try
    end try
end writeFile
```

and call it (replace the part of your code from `delay 4` to the end)

```
                       delay 4

     -- using a variable in path1 is where it screws up. try changing it to another variable value and it will have the same effect.
                        set myString to source of current tab
                        my writeFile(myString, titleVal)
                        exit repeat 

                    end tell
                end tell
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
 end run
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and efforts. Please see my answer. I fixed it with one line.

Comment: Nevertheless it's highly recommended to put code related to Scripting Additions out of application tell blocks and to use read/write with proper error handling. Once again, the `POSIX file` dance is not needed anyway because `open for access` and `write` considers POSIX paths

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed very easily by changing one line:

```
set newFile to POSIX file path1
```

to:

```
set newFile to (path1 as POSIX file)
```

But I don't know why. Seems like a bug since it worked without the variable. Please provide any details in the comments why this works over the original set newFile line.